# C++ No instance of overloaded function "sqrt" matches the argument list - Trying to find if a struct type array of numbers are perfect squares

Tags: c++, sqrt, perfect-square

I have a homework to do in C++, I'm trying to find if numbers from an array are perfect Square. Also, that array is dinamically allocated. Here is my code:

```
myVector perfectSquare(myVector *vect)
{
    myVector rez;
    rez.length = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vect->length; i++)
        if (vect[i] == sqrt(vect[i])*sqrt(vect[i])) // here it gives error
        {
            addToVector(&rez, vect->arr[i]);
        }

    return rez;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it all makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vect` is a **pointer** to a **struct** with an `arr` **field**, so you need to determine what field you are looking for:

```
sqrt(vect->arr[i]) * sqrt(vect->arr[i])
```

Please note, that writing `vect[i]` you mean a lot of *vect elements* and trying to get the *i'th* one *vect element*. But writing `vect->arr[i]` you mean a **pointer** to some exact *vect element*, trying to evaluate it's `arr` **field** and get *i'th* element of `arr` field.

Answer (score 0):

`vect` is not an array, so you can't use `vect[i]`, you should write `vect->arr[i]` - the `->` operator is used to access a member of struct. You should also `#include <math.h>`, in case you've forgotten it.